# On which android event view elements are available

Tags: java, android

I want to get a width and height of ImageView (for example). But if i use getWidth/getHeight methods in onCreate event, i get only zeroes.
Which event should I use to get real parameters of visual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When onCreate is called, the views aren't drawn yet, so there is no way to get your views sizes immediatly within this event.
Add an observer to the views you need the size and wait for onGlobalLayout event. This event will be thrown after the view is drawn.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (...)
    final View = findViewById(R.id.view);
    final ViewTreeObserver observer= view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("Log", "Height: " + view.getHeight());
                Log.d("Log", "Width: " + view.getWidth());
            }
        });
}
```